# Unable to store result of result set in variable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am having trouble in storing the b_id in a variable bId so that I can Use it further.
Please help.
It shows 'before Start of Result Set' error.

```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarian_db","root","tiger");
    PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement("select b_id from books  where Call_num= ?");
    ResultSet rs;
    ps2.setString(1, callNo);
    rs=ps2.executeQuery();
    bId = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(bId);
```

Comment: What is that trouble ? what is the error ?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set 
This is the error

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `rs.next()` for example :

```
if(rs.next()){
    bId = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(bId);
}
```

If you want multiple result you can use while :

```
while(rs.next()){
    bId = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(bId);
}
```